# How do I manipulate the equations of a circle and an ellipse such that I get exactly half of either sides with respect to the y-axis?

Tags: functional-analysis, graphing-functions, functional-calculus

I plotted the equations for a circle and an ellipse on a graphing software like so:

[Equations for the circle and ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzEhw.png)

How do I manipulate the following functions such that I get exactly half of the ellipse which is towards the left of the y-axis and exactly half of the circle which is towards the right of the y-axis? If it is still unclear as to what I am trying to ask about, I have drawn (in black) the desired outcome that I want on the previous image of the graph. The image is underneath.

[The function of the desired shape that I need help with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbv9A.png)

For reference -

Function for the circle: $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Function for the ellipse: $\left(\frac{x^2}{2^2}\right)+\left(\frac{y^2}{1^2}\right)=1$

Side-note: Since I am not allowed to attach images directly, the images are embedded into the hyperlinks. Please be so kind as to take some trouble to open the hyperlinks and help me out with my problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What’s wrong with a piecewise definition of your egg-shaped curve?

Comment: To pick some nits, neither of the equations that you’ve listed is a “function.”

Answer (score 0):

plug $$y^2=1-x^2$$ in the equation of the Ellipse, this means $$\frac{x^2}{4}+1-x^2=1$$

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Plugging this is giving me a straight line which is essentially the y-axis.